# Return an instance of a std::unique_ptr that automatically deduces the base and parent classes

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

I have a parent class `Window`

```
class Window 
{
public:
    Window(int x, int y);
    virtual void Display();
    virtual ~Window();
}
```

and a base class `Console`

```
class Console : public Window 
{
public:
    Console(int x, int y);
    virtual void Display();
    virtual ~Console();
}
```

I store the results in a manager class with the following signature:

```
class WindowManager
{
public:
    WindowManager() {};
    void AddWindow(int x, int y)
    {
        m_Windows.emplace(nle::WindowType::RenderWindow, std::make_unique<nle::Window>(x,y))
    }
    void AddConsole(int x, int y)
    {
       m_Windows.emplace(nle::WindowType::ConsoleWindow, std::make_unique<nle::Console>(x,y));
    }

    nle::Window* GetRenderWindow()
    {
        return m_Windows[nle::WindowType::RenderWindow].get();
    }

    nle::Window* GetConsoleWindow()
    {
        return m_Windows[nle::WindowType::ConsoleWindow].get();
    }
private:
        std::unordered_map<WindowType, std::unique_ptr<nle::Window>> m_Windows;
};
```

When calling the Get___Window functions the base class is always called, I tried returning a reference to the windows instead of a pointer but the base class is still called, I've seen references of others doing a for ranged loop to directly access the container:

```
for(const window& : m_Windows)
{
    window->Display();
}
```

This would work, but i would like to avoid using direct access to my manager.

An example of this code is:

```
static WindowManager m_WindowManager; // static purely for simplicity to avoid using a class for SO
int main()
{
    InitResources();
    while(1)
    {
        DisplayWindow();
    }
    return 1;
}

void InitResources()
{
     m_WindowManager.AddConsoleWindow(1080, 720);
}

void DisplayWindow()
{
     m_WindowManager.GetConsoleWindow()->Display(); // Base class is called
}
```

Comment: Well, you constructed two `nle::Window` with `std::make_unique`, so that's what you get out. Just construct a `Console` in `AddConsole` :)

Comment: That was an error from my copy and pasting, it still does not deduce the proper type even when emplacing a Console Window.

Comment: Then we'll need an actual [mcve] because `std::unique_ptr`s sure are polymorphic.

Comment: I've added a complete, minimal example. Am I required to dynamic_cast the pointers i obtain from `GetConsoleWindow()`?

Comment: A complete example implies that others can actually compile it. Just copy everything to a single source file until it compiles and then strip it down.

Comment: @OmarMartinez Really the best thing to do is a link to an online compiler/runner: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/. Put the code there, actually write out basic implementations for the functions (they can just print "I am base", etc), then comment some line of code: "I expected foo to be printed", and when you compile and run, it prints something else.

Comment: What do you mean by *"when calling the Get___Window functions the base class is always called"*? Your Get___Window does not invoke any function of your custom classes.